# Selectively get certain arrays from inside an array in JSON using JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I've been trying to get some fields out of a very long and complicated json format but not getting the output I want.

MY current spec obtains all events from the event array and lists them in the output. I'm unsure how to select specific events and only output those. Am not quite sure of the syntax

My JSON:

```
{
  "rootid": "19718",
  "clloadm": "2021-06-01T22:40:02",
  "clload": "2021-06-01T21:21:39",
  "date": "2021-05-25T21:52:30",
  "events": [
    {
      "done": {
        "id": "e0",
        "value": "2021-05-29T08:08:19"
      },
      "id": "e0_event",
      "started": {
        "id": "e0",
        "value": "2021-05-29T08:08:19"
      },
      "status": "complete"
    },
    {
      "done": {
        "id": "e1",
        "value": "2021-05-27T02:20:25"
      },
      "id": "e1_event",
      "started": {
        "id": "e1",
        "value": "2021-05-27T02:20:25"
      },
      "status": "complete"
    },
    {
      "done": {
        "id": "e2",
        "value": "2021-05-29T08:08:19"
      },
      "id": "e2_event",
      "started": {
        "id": "e2",
        "value": "2021-05-29T08:08:19"
      },
      "status": "complete"
    },
    {
      "done": {
        "id": "e3",
        "value": "2021-05-29T08:08:19"
      },
      "id": "e3_event",
      "started": {
        "id": "e3",
        "value": "2021-05-29T08:08:19"
      },
      "status": "complete"
    },
    {
      "done": {
        "id": "e4",
        "value": "2021-05-29T08:08:19"
      },
      "id": "e4_event",
      "started": {
        "id": "e4",
        "value": "2021-05-29T08:08:19"
      },
      "status": "complete"
    }
  ],
  "ids": [
    {
      "id": "id",
      "source": "source",
      "value": "value"
    },
    {
      "id": "new_id",
      "source": "new_source",
      "value": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

My Jolt Spec that gets all events for now:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "rootid": "rootid",
      "clloadm": "clloadm",
      "clload": "clload",
      "date": "date",
      "events": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@value": "@id"
          }
        }
      },
      "ids": {
        "*": {
          "@value": "@id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The output I get:

```
{
  "rootid" : "19718",
  "clloadm" : "2021-06-01T22:40:02",
  "clload" : "2021-06-01T21:21:39",
  "date" : "2021-05-25T21:52:30",
  "e0" : [ "2021-05-29T08:08:19", "2021-05-29T08:08:19" ],
  "e1" : [ "2021-05-27T02:20:25", "2021-05-27T02:20:25" ],
  "e2" : [ "2021-05-29T08:08:19", "2021-05-29T08:08:19" ],
  "e3" : [ "2021-05-29T08:08:19", "2021-05-29T08:08:19" ],
  "e4" : [ "2021-05-29T08:08:19", "2021-05-29T08:08:19" ],
  "id" : "value",
  "new_id" : "value"
}
```

The output I would like

```
{
  "rootid" : "19718",
  "clloadm" : "2021-06-01T22:40:02",
  "clload" : "2021-06-01T21:21:39",
  "date" : "2021-05-25T21:52:30",
  "e0" : [ "2021-05-29T08:08:19", "2021-05-29T08:08:19" ],
  "e4" : [ "2021-05-29T08:08:19", "2021-05-29T08:08:19" ],
  "id" : "value",
  "new_id" : "value"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the individual keys `e0` and `e4` as conditional cases for `@id` key while rewriting the rest of the *key-value pairs* through `"*":"&"` representation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "events": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@id": {
              "e0": { "@(2,value)": "&" },
              "e4": { "@(2,value)": "&" }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "ids": {
        "*": {
          "@value": "@id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi! Thankyou very much! This is exactly what I was looking for!